# Cypress.io testing for drop down list

Tags: angular, cypress

I have an angular 2+ application and I am using cypress.io for E2E testing.

I am having trouble creating a test where I have multiple drop down list.

I want to write cypress.io code to select a drop down list, choose my desired option, and move on to the next drop down list. I am unable to invoke drop down list, choose the value, etc.

My test gets stopped as follows:

[image]

Here is my code so far..

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Reminders application test harness', () => {

  it(`create contact reminder and delete contact and reminder`, () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/home');
    cy.contains('Logout').click();
    cy.contains('Login').click();
    cy.get('#mat-input-0').type('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
    cy.get('#mat-input-1').type('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    cy.get('[fxlayout="column"] > .space-top').click();

    cy.contains('Contacts').click();
    cy.get('#mat-input-5').type('bill');
    cy.get('#mat-input-6').type('gates');
    cy.get('#mat-input-7').type('7145551212');
    cy.get('.mat-raised-button').click();
    cy.get(
      '[style="left: calc(((33.3333% - 6.66667px) + 10px) * 1); width: calc(((33.3333% - 6.66667px) * 1) + 0px); top: 0px; height: calc(250px);"] > .mat-figure > .mat-card > .mat-card-actions > .update-button > .mat-button-wrapper > .mat-icon'
    ).click();
    cy.get(
      '#mat-select-0 > .mat-select-trigger > .mat-select-arrow-wrapper > .mat-select-arrow'
    ).click();
    // .get('Daily')
    // .click();
  });
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Posting the HTML you're working with will help us help you.

Comment: This is what happens when I run the test..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using the following code. Where the name property in my drop down is "freq". Thanks

```
cy.get('[name="freq"]').click();
cy.get('mat-option')
.contains('Daily')
.click();
```

Comment: Btw I'm not sure how your dropdown is generated, but it' not a good practice to use element texts for testing. Those can easily change in the future and it makes your test fail. 

Best practice is adding the `data-cy` attribute to the element. So if there's a way to add this tag to your dropdown option elements, do that and than you can get them with `cy.get(''option[data-cy=<ATTR_VAL>'')`. If you add support of other languages in the future, test will still pass. Ofc, it's sometimes not possible to add `data-cy` tag. Just wanted to let you know.